# How to Capture the screen of Gear VR and display on laptop or projector

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy-gear, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I have an app which I have built for Samsung Gear VR with Samsung s6 device. I would like to show the view of the running app in the headset to the audience in the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a google chromecast and try streaming to a TV or a projector. Note hovever that this may affect the framerate.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this yesterday and found one of the simplest ways of doing it was to install the Mobizen app on the 'phone and then [log into the Mobizen site](https://www.mobizen.com/?locale=en).

This mirrors the display and allows full screen.

As mentioned in the other answer, it also slowed the framerate and reduced the time before the 'phone needed a break to cool down.